# Why theses two divs doesn't render the same way?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

When I run this, it doesn't render the same way although it is the same from my beginner pov.
For example, I can't expand the first one div in the console dev tools, but I can expand the second one !

[Link, I haven't the right to post images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvegy.png)

Why ?

```
import React from "react"

export default function App() {

    const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const lol = setTimeout(() => setTime(prev => prev + 1), 100)
        return () => clearTimeout(lol)
    }
        , [time]
    )

    function ComponentTimer() {
        return <div> (I can't open this div in the console) Time : {time / 10} sec</div>
    }

    return (
        <main>
            {<ComponentTimer />}
            <div> (but I can open this one) Time : {time / 10} sec</div>
        </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: Because on the first div the change detection renders the whole component,
and in the second div it only renders the text in the component.
and all this happens every 100ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first It is a component and you are changing state after `100ms` which will re-render the whole component. If you want to see both exactly like same all you have to do is extract `ComponentTimer` outside and pass `time` as a props as:

[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5yhmjb?file=src%2FApp.js)

```
function ComponentTimer({ time }) {
  return (
    <div> (I can't open this div in the console) Time : {time / 10} sec</div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const lol = setTimeout(() => setTime((prev) => prev + 1), 100);
    return () => clearTimeout(lol);
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <main>
      <ComponentTimer time={time} />
      <div> (but I can open this one) Time : {time / 10} sec</div>
    </main>
  );
}
```